# TRIM doesn't remove inner whitespaces

Tags: sql

I try to remove all whitespaces inside a string. For this, I use TRIM() function. Unfortunately it doesn't work as expected, inner whitespaces (between 35 and 'A') remain untouched:

```
  select TRIM('Hopkins 35   A Street') as Street
```

Column type is `nvarchar`. The funny thing is that this function works fine (using example from above) when executed on W3Schools (TRIM function example): https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_trim.asp.
I can use `replace` on this string and replace `' '` into `''` without a problem. I work on SQL Server 18.7.1 (2020)

Comment: Trim works as it is defined - "remove leading and trailing spaces from a string." so yes, you also need to use replace

Comment: Ok so pls follow W3Schools link from my post a you will see it removes inner whitespaces as well, not only leading/trailing ones. It seems working for all whitespaces everywhere

Comment: I went to the link, and nope- it does not trim middle spaces. Are you talking about the column alias TrimmedString?  That's a column name.  "SQL Tutorial" is the value.

Comment: If you run the "try it yourself" link, the result is `SQL Tutorial!`, with the space in the middle retained. Your assertions are false.

Comment: If you removed all whitespaces then the address would make no sense anyway. `Hopkins 35   A Street` would be 'Hopkins35AStreet'?

Comment: That website, however, does make it LOOK as though multiple spaces are trimmed to single spaces. But that's the HTML rendering of the string, nothing to do with the SQL.  Run this `select len(TRIM('Hopkins 35  
 A Street'))` *(With the extra spaces, which SO's HTML rendering are hiding)* on that website and you'll see that no spaces have been removed at all.

Comment: @MatBailie ok got it now, it's all about rendering

Comment: By the way... SQL Server 18.7.1 does not exist. That version seems to be the version of SQL Server Management Studio you are using. If you want to see the SQL Server version, you could execute `PRINT @@VERSION`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use TRIM like this you are only removing leading and trailing spaces from a string. To remove also spaces in between you should change to:

```
select TRIM(' ' FROM 'Hopkins 35   A Street') as Street
```

UPDATE: if you meant to remove all spaces you should use

```
SELECT REPLACE('Hopkins 35 A Street', ' ', '')
```

TRIM is only intended to make a double space become a single one

Comment: I executed your code and whitespaces in between are not removed. As I mentioned in my post - you can remove inner whitespaces using TRIM in this W3Schools example.

Comment: Ok, I got it, TRIM is intended to remove only double spaces, not single ones. To remove all spaces you need to use SELECT REPLACE('Hopkins 35   A Street', ' ', '')

Answer (score 0):

"Trimming" means the removal of whitespace from the start and/or the end of a string value. It never means (and has never meant to mean) the removal of whitespace *within* a string value (enclosed by non-whitespace characters).

You can indeed use the `TRIM` function with a `FROM` in its argument to specify other characters than whitespace to trim. In that case, the `TRIM` function will remove the specified characters *from the start and the end of the string, but not within the string (enclosed by other characters)*.

In other words: the specified characters will be treated as if they were whitespace as well, but specifying them so will not affect the trimming behavior/algorithm itself.

Check out the [sample on Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#b--removes-specified-characters-from-both-sides-of-string):

```sql
SELECT TRIM( '.,! ' FROM  '     #     test    .') AS Result;
```

produces this result: `#     test`

Answer (score 0):

TRIM function will only remove only the leading and tailing spaces in the data. It cannot remove all the spaces in the data. I mean it cannot remove all the spaces if there are any spaces in the data like 'Hello World'. TRIM cannot remove the space between the word Hello and World and make it look like 'HelloWorld'. If you want to remove all the spaces, you can use the REPLACE function. In the REPLACE function you can replace the space with any character/number/symbol. If you don't need any you can simply remove the space with ''. like

SELECT REPLACE('Hopkins 35 A Street', ' ', '')